# I want to implement peer to peer video call in nodejs using webrtc

Tags: node.js, api, express

i want to call a route and then that route will open in browse and starts transmitting video stream . i used getUserMedia api .

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Kurento Media Server.** That's the best opensource media server available. I've worked with it and implemented live peer to peer call.

It provide wide variety of pre-built tutorials. e.g.

- One-to-One Call
- One-to-Many Call
- Adding filters while video chat

Further, it provides different flavours in Java, Javascript and NodeJS.

You can see the detailed documentation [here](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: please provide me code for one to one call . i have studied kurento but didnot understood their documentation . i am using ejs to show that video on browser

Comment: You can find the one to one call tutorial on this [this](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/node/tutorial-one2one.html) link. It has very simple steps to follow. 
And please accept my answer

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

include this in your library

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/peerjs/0.3.9/peer.min.js"></script>`

make a peer

```
var peer = new Peer();
```

connect

```
var conn = peer.connect('another-peers-id');
// on open will be launch when you successfully connect to PeerServer
conn.on('open', function(){
  // here you have conn.id
  conn.send('hi!');
});
```

receive

```
peer.on('connection', function(conn) {
  conn.on('data', function(data){
    // Will print 'hi!'
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

so now for calls you should be fine with

```
var getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, function(stream) {
  var call = peer.call('another-peers-id', stream);
  call.on('stream', function(remoteStream) {
    // Show stream in some video/canvas element.
  });
}, function(err) {
  console.log('Failed to get local stream' ,err);
});
```

and for answer

```
var getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
peer.on('call', function(call) {
  getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, function(stream) {
    call.answer(stream); // Answer the call with an A/V stream.
    call.on('stream', function(remoteStream) {
      // Show stream in some video/canvas element.
    });
  }, function(err) {
    console.log('Failed to get local stream' ,err);
  });
});
```

I hope this helps you, btw you can use Kurento Media Server https://github.com/ESTOS/kurento-media-server

Comment: I am new to nodejs,  can you provide me full step by step guidance and please write that code in a route like router.get('/xyz', (req,res) => {// your code here })